# Set DocLib Title column in C#

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library

Environment: SharePoint 2013, reasonably recently patched.

I'm running the following code in a Sequential Workflow:

```
...
targetItem["Title"] = "Test";
targetItem.Update();
...
```

When I log the value before the update, the title value is "Test".  When I log the title after the update, the value is blank.

I've tried various combinations of Update/SystemUpdate and Title/vti_title

The document I'm testing with does not have a Title property set in its metadata.

Why would updating cause the value to be lost?  Other fields are maintaining their values properly so it is just the Title column.  How can I set the Title value and have it stick?

Comment: What is the targetItem? File or forlder, new added item or existed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095597/how-to-set-the-name-of-a-new-splistitem-programmatically?newreg=80963d5d2433416c9d7d9e69805c0233 - may be useful

Comment: targetItem is the document I'm testing with.  It could be either a new item or an existing item.  The workflow runs for both.